# Elasticsearch ping() with Python is returning False

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Trying to ping to elasticsearch `https://localhost:9200` from Python. `es.ping()` is returning False.

From browser I am able to connect to `https://localhost:9200` with username and password (asked only for first time).

```
def connect_elasticsearch():
    es = None
    es = Elasticsearch(['https://localhost:9200'], basic_auth=('elastic', 'password'))
    print(es)
    if es.ping():
        print('Yupiee  Connected ')
    else:
        print('Awww it could not connect!')
    return es

es1 = connect_elasticsearch()
```

Output:

```
<Elasticsearch(['https://localhost:9200'])>
Awww it could not connect!
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to connect to kibana ? Elasticsearch doesn't have a Gui

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

As [per the documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.4.2/api.html?highlight=ping#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.ping),

> This API call can fail either at the transport layer (due to connection errors or timeouts) or from a non-2XX HTTP response (due to authentication or authorization issues).

## Solution

To be able to go on, please use the line below

```py
print(es.info())
```

This should help you understand what is going wrong.

I suspect the certificate are not trusted.